# Setting ImageButton background by reading storage in android

Tags: android, storage, imagebutton

I am using the following to open storage and set the background of an ImageButton.

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        //String[] filePathColumn = {Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();


        imgLogo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


    }
```

But even if in manifest permissions exist I cant set the Imagebutton background

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I get...
    requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,bmOptions);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,parent.getWidth(),parent.getHeight(),true);
imgLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Also, check the image view's visibility.